# Can helm install multi-component application in single run?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm

From Helm docs:

> Helm helps you manage Kubernetes applications.

My application consists of multiple components. Say Client Component, Server Component, Connectors etc.
At present we deploy each of these components independently using `kubectl`.

Just wondering, on using helm can every component of the application be deployed using one `helm install` command.

Answer (score 2):

That is definitely possible. You can use subcharts to install several things in one run.
https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/

The link above might be the right place to start.

Comment: but, on further thought - transitive dependencies(which can be handled using subcharts) are not same as application components.  Ex: It might be desirable to install both client and server on some machines. But neither client or server are dependent on each other - they can exist independent of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Helm doesn't deal with this case well.  You hit on the main problem in a comment: if your connector needs a Redis cache, and your backend needs a Redis cache, a Helm "umbrella chart" will only install a single Redis to be shared across components, and you usually don't want this.

There are a variety of wrapper tools that can do this, though.  Two open-source tools I've looked at recently are [Helmsman](https://github.com/Praqma/helmsman) and [Helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile).  Both take a list of charts to install and options.  Helmfile has a number of ways to apply Helm-style templating to its own configuration and to values files, which adds a lot of complexity but also makes it possible to support many mostly-similar clusters.  Helmsman doesn't support this templating and is correspondingly similar.  If you're heavily invested in generic automation tools like Ansible or Terraform already, you can also use these to install Helm charts.

Comment: further, are transitive dependencies supported or just dependencies up to one level.

Comment: Helm supports transitive dependencies, but shares them across an entire chart installation.  If A depends on B and C, B depends on D, and C depends on D, then `helm install A` will install A, B, C, and D; but B and C will share the one copy of D.  The higher-level tools I mention effectively work by doing multiple `helm installs` so aren't limited this way.